# How to synchronize observables from list?

Tags: rx-java

I want to perform an operator on each item of a list. The next item of list should be triggered when the operator of previous item is finished. At the moment (see code) the operator is performed for all items parallel. How can I avoid the parallel processing?

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(3);
    strings.add("String1");
    strings.add("String2");
    strings.add("String3");

    Observable<String> stringObservables = Observable.from(strings);
    stringObservables
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .lift(new TranslateViewOperator( ... parameters ... ))
            .subscribe();
```

The operator is defined as follows:

```
public class TranslateViewOperator implements Observable.Operator<View, View> {

long         duration;
Interpolator interpolator;
int          runningAnimations;
float        xTransform;

public TranslateViewOperator(float xTransform, long duration, Interpolator interpolator) {
    super();
    this.duration = duration;
    this.interpolator = interpolator;
    this.xTransform = xTransform;
}

@Override
public Subscriber<? super View> call(final Subscriber<? super View> subscriber) {

    return new Subscriber<View>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(View view) {
            runningAnimations++;
            System.out.println("TranslateViewOperator.onNext");
            ViewCompat.animate(view)
                      .translationX(xTransform - runningAnimations)
                      .scaleX(1f)
                      .scaleY(1f)
                      .setStartDelay(1000)
                      .setDuration(1000)
                      .setInterpolator(interpolator)
                      .withEndAction(() -> {
                          System.out.println("Animation finished");
                      });
        }
    };
}
```

}

The println output is as follows:

```
TranslateViewOperator.onNext
TranslateViewOperator.onNext
TranslateViewOperator.onNext
Animation finished
Animation finished
Animation finished
```

That means at first all animations are started here. But I want to start the next animation when previous animation is finished.

Comment: Why are you using an operator ? you can use a Completable for example that complete at the end of your animation (see Completable.fromEmitter) than you can concat all your Completable.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Bindings.bindContent(list1, list2);

Available with JavaFX.

Generates a content binding between an {@link javafx.collections.ObservableList} and a {@link java.util.List}.

If the content of the {@code ObservableList} changes, the {@code List} will be updated automatically.